# Inserting and button disable putting all together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have nested records of a table that i insert to a different table of a database with ajax, when i click on a particular button the value changes to data sent and so forth for the descending buttons. i perform this with two scripts that works perfectly, one insert data without refreshing and the other disables the particular button on click and changes the value to data sent. Now i want to put it all together so it becomes one.

Insertion

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "calls/insert_fryd.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {
```

Disable button

```
$(function(){
 $(".btn-style").click(function(){
    $(this).val('data sent');
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are the $(".btn-style") button and the button you click to submit the form are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(function(){});` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Just place both pieces of code inside a single DOM ready handler. e.g.

```
$(function () {

    $("form").on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calls/insert_fryd.asp",
            data: data
        }).success(function () {});
    });

    $(".btn-style").click(function () {
        $(this).val('data sent');
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });

});
```

Assuming ".btn-style" matches your submit button you can simplify this to:

```
$(function () {

    $("form").on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Disable submit button on this specific form
        $('.btn-style', this).val('data sent').prop('disabled', true);

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calls/insert_fryd.asp",
            data: data
        }).success(function () {
        });
    });
});
```

The subsequent issue found (*not working in Chrome*) is down to using `disabled` via `attr`. For genuine properties (like `checked` and `disabled`) always use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: @blay: Use `prop` instead of `attr` for `disabled`... Have corrected code. Try that.

Comment: sorry, then it's a mistake. i'm correcting it. sorry please.